# Input impedance of GPIO pins vs. current protecting resistor

Tags: resistors, gpio, input-impedance

Novice here.

I have read that the input impedance of GPIO pins on a microcontroller might be in the order of 20 megohm. I’m trying to understand why we then might need a current limiting resistor with a value around 100 ohm.

Why would we need an extra 100 ohm when we already have 20 megohm?

Example circuit from the [video](https://youtu.be/NAl-ULEattw)

[image]

As I said, novice! Thanks for your patience

Comment: Most cmos chips have ESD protection diodes. Exceed the voltage rails and these diodes conduct, with the input impedance dropping rapidly.  Thus 100R resistors to limit the possible fault current.

Comment: In *which* application do you want a 100 Ω current limiting resistor? It's not something we generally add just everywhere! I'm not sure where that resistance comes from. It's not a value that seems overly useful to me.

Comment: Thanks. The 100 ohm value came from a tutorial on connecting a switch to the GPIO.

Comment: @user2162871:  A link to that tutorial (and a copy of hte schematic and some quotes) would be a good thing in your question.

Comment: So does the input impedance have any role in limiting current? And if there is a large current, and we don’t have the “protection” on the 100 Ohm resistor, then the protection diodes are at risk? Thanks

Comment: Yes. Apologies. https://youtu.be/NAl-ULEattw

The relevant bit is 3:40 in.   And the resistor is 1K, not 0.1K

Comment: No, I don't mean a link to a video.  I thought you had schematics and explanations instead of "watch 20 minutes if video to pick out the bit you need."

Comment: Sorry. I did give the time where the issue raised so you wouldn’t have to “watch 20 minutes and pick out the bit you need “

Comment: Provide a screenshot, not a link to video and time where to skip. Questions must be standalone and understandable without watching a video first.

Comment: Here's a screenshot - https://imgur.com/a/Gj8Udfw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be many reasons for putting a 100 ohm in series with a GPIO input for protection.

As the GPIO pin can be accidentally be configured as output, there is less chance of permanent damage if the pin is an output pushing high and pushbutton shorts it to ground.

Comment: Ahh. So I see that. Thanks. If it’s not misconfigured, is there a need for an external current limiting resistance or will the input  impedance do that job?

Comment: In theory, no need for an external series resistor, pushbutton can connect directly to input pin. But there still might be many other reasons why it is there.

Comment: Thanks - and I will post screenshots in future!